# Reactjs functional component common logic extraction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I have a few functional components with a few common variables and functions. Please see below.

```js
const Customer = () => {
   const [isReleased, setIsReleased] = useState(false)

   const release = () => {
        setIsReleased(true)
   }
}

const Order = () => {
   const [isReleased, setIsReleased] = useState(false)

   const release = () => {
        setIsReleased(true)
   }
}
```

As you can see from the above code fragment, the `release()` function has common logic. It accesses component's variables/functions.

Is there a way to move this `release()` function to a common file and import it from each component?

Please note that the `release()` method should be able to access scoped variables and functions of the caller.

**Update**

Below is the actual content of the `release()` function. I have put `this.` to denote that it refers to the variables/functions in the caller.

```js
const release = () => {
  if (action === "new") {
    history.push(`/customers/new`)
  } else if (action === "save") {
    (async () => {
      try {
        if (this.dataMode === "new") {
          this.setMessage()
          this.setFormStatus("updating")
          let _res = await this.customer_api_create(this.formData)
          if ((_res.status === 200) && (_res.data.status === "success")) {
            this.setFormStatus()
            history.replace({ pathname: `/customers/${_res.data.data[0].id}` })
          }
        } else if (this.dataMode === "edit") {
          this.setFormStatus("updating")
          this.setMessage()
          let _res = await this.customer_api_update(this.formData)
          if ((_res.status === 200) && (_res.data.status === "success")) {
            this.setFormStatus()
            this.setMessage({ type: "info", text: "Saved" })
            this.setFormData(_res.data.data[0])
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        this.openMessageBox({
          prompt: e.response.data.message,
          type: this.constants.app.MessageBoxType.MB_Error,
          buttons: this.constants.app.MessageBoxButton.MB_Ok,
          show: true,
          setResult: () => console.log(this.constants.app.MessageBoxResult.MB_Ok)
        })
        this.setFormStatus("updating_error")
      }
    })();
  } else if (action === "del") {
    this.openMessageBox({
      prompt: `{ "": ["Are you sure you want to delete context customer?"] }`,
      type: this.constants.app.MessageBoxType.MB_Warning,
      buttons: this.constants.app.MessageBoxButton.MB_YesNo,
      show: true,
      setResult: (val) => {
        this.openMessageBox({ show: false })
        this.setShouldRecordDeleted(val)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest redux.

Comment: You *could* abstract the `isReleased` state, setter, and `release` function into a custom hook, but you'd end up with about the same amount of code since these are such simple blocks. While you have named the state and callback the same, they ***really*** aren't the same code. You can't abstract state out of a React component. I think any attempt to make the code in your snippets "more DRY" will just unnecessarily make it more complex and harder to work with and maintain. As I said, look at the answers below and you've not really reduced any code.

Comment: @drew-reese Actually `release()` method has a lot of lines of code. Not just `setIsReleased(true)`. That's why I wanted to abstract it away.

Comment: Please share a more accurate and comprehensive code representation. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DrewReese I updated the question with more information.

Comment: Only two solutions I can see is using either [redux](https://redux.js.org/) or [react context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: @Pasi-D [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) could probably also work and be quite a bit easier to implement/use. OP doesn't really need global state, which is more what redux and the Context API serve a purpose for. It seems these two components really only share the state variable names and implementation. We still really need more complete and comprehensive component code examples from OP though to have better context.

Answer (score -1):

You can declare the function release in a different file and pass the `setIsReleased` method as an argument

```
import {release} from 'release';  

const Customer = () => {
       const [isReleased, setIsReleased] = useState(false)
       release(setIsReleased)
    }
```

And in your release.js file

```
export const release = (setIsReleased) => {
   setIsReleased(true)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not practical since the `release()` method will access many more variables and functions. It is not just calling `setIsReleased()` method. I didn't include them in my question to make it simpler. But I understand now that I have misled the reader by not mentioning that `release()` has around 30 lines of code in it.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe callback solve the problem, how about this?

anotherfile.js

```js
    const release = (param, setter) => {
        if (true){
            setter(true)
        }
    }
```

yourfile.js

```js
    import {release} from "anotherfile"
    const Customer = () => {
       const [isReleased, setIsReleased] = useState(false)
       release([parameter],setIsReleased)
    }
```